# Python- Function object in class

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class new:
    i=1
    def __init__(self):
        name='sakthi'

    def add(self,one,two):
         return one+two

k=new.add

print(k)
```

When I execute the above program. I get `function new.add at 0x0068E270` as output.

Can anyone help me to understand, what has happened and what kind of operation can I do with value `k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new.add` value you're assigning to `k` is a function. In Python 2, it would have been a special "unbound method" object, but your output suggests you're using Python 3 (where unbound methods don't exist any more except conceptually).

Like any function, you can call `k` if you want, passing whatever values are appropriate for `self`, `one` and `two`. For instance, `k("foo", 1, 2)` (which will return `3`).

Traditionally the `self` argument should be an instance of the `new` class, though in Python 3 that isn't enforced by anything (a check for this was the purpose of unbound method objects in Python 2). So passing a string in the example above worked fine, since `self` is not used in the function body for anything. (More complicated methods will usually fail if you pass an inappropriate argument as `self`.)

The usual way to call methods is to create an instance of a class first, then call the method on the instance. This causes the instance to be passed as the first argument automatically:

```
x = new()
x.add(1, 2) # returns 3, x got passed as self
```

Comment: Yes. I am using python 3

Answer (score 1):

`function new.add at 0x0068E270` In CPython, will be the address of `k`. Since `k` is just a function you can still do something like `print(k('foo', 1, 2))` that Will print `5`